# Find first div with class use simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple html dom to get data from a website.

My problem is when i find a div with a specify class it return all the div tag which have that class. 
I'm want content in the first div with that class only.

My code is like this

```
$html = file_get_html('myurl');
$e = $html->find("div[class=myclass]",0);
echo $e->plaintext;
```

How can i get the first div with myclass only.
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this alternative method,

```
$e = $html->find("div[class=myclass]");
echo $e[0]->plaintext;
```

However I think, it should also work with `$html->find("div[class=myclass]",0);`
it could be because you are using old version of `simple_html_dom`

For me, I only had to change $html = `file_get_html(myurl);` to `$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents(myurl));` for my version of `simple_html_dom` with `php 7`

Comment: ty, i tried but the result still the same with my way. 
however when i try 
`$e = $html->find("div[class=myclass]",-1);` 
it return exact the last div with myclass.

Comment: Can you share the url and the class name? I think it can happen when the element you are trying to target has the same classname for its parent.

Comment: url: http://www.latimes.com/sports/la-sp-dodgers-maeda-hernandez-20171011-story.html
classname: trb_ar_page

Comment: I think it returns what it is supposed to, I get all the content from the first trb_ar_page class. https://jpst.it/16FPZ

Comment: i checked again, these 2 element with trb_ar_page class are not parent and children, there is 1 different things between them is one have data-content-page="1" and the other have data-content-page="2", can i do something with this?

Comment: Check my link where I shared the output, let me know if you get the same.

Comment: To use data attribute you can do $e = $html->find("div[data-content-page=2]",0);

Comment: that's exactly what i need. but why my code still didn't return the right result. Can it because of php version or php simple html dom version? i'm using php 5.6

Comment: It could be because you are using old version of simple_html_dom. Download the new one. And try again, if the   file_get_html function doesn't work, consider opting for the change I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: i change simple html dom from 1.11 to 1.5 and it's work, ty so much

Comment: Glad I could help :)